# Java-11 in Eclipse Version: 2018-12 (4.10.0)

Tags: java, eclipse, java-11

I downloaded Eclipse Version : 2018-12 to run my App on JDK-11. I understand that I also need to install this Plugin in Eclipse https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-11-support-eclipse-2018-09-49

But when I install this Plugin am stopped with the error

`No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core,1.7.4.v20190206-1730`

Also my eclipse workspace still seeks JRE version. Not sure how to resolve this, can anyone suggest anything?

Comment: 2018-12 doesn't need anything extra to support Java 11, that add on is for the previous version (2018-09)

Comment: ok thanks .. How to configure the JRE then ? any idea pls ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. Exactly what errors are you getting?

Comment: Eclipse is forcing me to select a `JRE` for my workspace and there is no `JRE-Package` that am aware of for `Open-JDK-11` . I couldn't successfully import my app in to eclipse because of this

Comment: Just use the JDK. There is no separate JRE for Java 11.

Comment: Make sure the Java 11 JDK is added in _Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs_.

Comment: Its done. Thanks